# Modifying macro to only apply to selection, not entire sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that takes a column and basically duplicates each row:

```
Sub Duper()
Dim LR As Long
Dim i As Long

LR = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For i = LR To 1 Step -1
    Rows(i).Copy
    Range(Rows(i + 1), Rows(i + 1)).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next i

End Sub
```

*input*

> 101
>   
> 102
>   
> 103
>   
> 104
>   
> 105

*output*

> 101
>   
> 101
>   
> 102
>   
> 102
>   
> 103
>   
> 103
>   
> 104
>   
> 104
>   
> 105
>   
> 105

However, I cannot add new data and then only duplicate the new data as the macro applies to the entire sheet.

What do I need to add to this macro that will allow me to only to run the macro against selected cells?

Answer (score 1):

To do just the Selected cells:

```
Sub Duper()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = (Selection.Row + Selection.Rows.Count - 1) To Selection.Row Step -1
        Rows(i).Copy
        Range(Rows(i + 1), Rows(i + 1)).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next i

End Sub
```

So select the cells you want, then run this.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you work with arrays rather than loops (for speed):

```
Sub EddieBetts()
 Dim rng1 As Range
 Dim X, Y
 Dim lngCnt As Long

 Set rng1 = Selection
 X = Application.Transpose(Selection)
 ReDim Y(1 To UBound(X) * 2)
 For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(X)
   Y(2 * lngCnt - 1) = X(lngCnt)
   Y(2 * lngCnt) = X(lngCnt)
 Next
 rng1.Offset(rng1.Rows.Count).Rows.Insert xlDown
 rng1.Resize(rng1.Rows.Count * 2).Value2 = Application.Transpose(Y)
End Sub
```